# TestNG doesnot pick a specific test

Tags: java, maven, testng

I am trying to run a specific test from the commandline, instead the command is running all the tests in in the module.
my testngxml is

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="BusContracts_suite">
        <test name="TestNG test for BusContracts Testing ">
            <classes>
                <class name="testRunners.busContractsRunner">
<!--                    <methods>-->
<!--                        <include name="runTest_BusContracts"/>-->
<!--                    </methods>-->
                </class>
            </classes>
        </test>
</suite>
```

and my test runner is

```
package testRunners;

import config.PropertyManager;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature;
import exceptions.VariableNotDefinedException;
import objects.TestNGCucumberParams;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import utils.ReportHandler;

import java.util.*;


@CucumberOptions(glue = "stepDefinitions/", features = "src/test/resources/features/BusContracts", tags = {"@BusContractsTesting.s2"},
        plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber-html-report",
                "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                "pretty:target/cucumber-report/cucumber-pretty.txt",
                "usage:target/cucumber-report/cucumber-usage.json"
        })

public class busContractsRunner {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(busContractsRunner.class);
    TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());

    @DataProvider(name = "OperatorDetails")
    public String[] loadOperatorDetails() throws VariableNotDefinedException {
        String[] operators = System.getSystemProperty("Operatorabbr").split(",");
        return operators;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void init() {
        LOG.info("setup method");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        LOG.info("tearDown method");
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }

    @Test (dataProvider = "OperatorDetails",skipFailedInvocations = true)
    public void runTest_BusContracts(String[] operatorDetails) {
        String operatorabbr = "";
        TestNGCucumberParams.getInstance().setTestRunnerDataMap(new HashMap<String, String>());
        for(String operator:operatorDetails){
            operatorabbr = operator;
            System.setSystemProperty("Operatorabbr",operator);
        }
        for (CucumberFeature cucumberFeature: testNGCucumberRunner.getFeatures()){
            TestNGCucumberParams.getInstance().getTestRunnerDataMap().put("$ScenarioDesc$", "MIS extract                    for Bus Contracts" + " - " + operatorabbr);
            testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature);
        }
    }
}
```

maven command i am running is

```
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile="src\test\resources\testNG\busContracts.xml"
```

I have tried including the method name , which is commented out in the code, not working , Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this command please, Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as a `suiteFile` property. Did you read the documentation for Surefire? https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

Comment: yes I have tried this as well,  mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile="src\test\resources\testNG\busContracts.xml"

Comment: I don't see `suiteXmlFile` as a user property in the documentation either.

Comment: I have got this working earlier, but not right now for this scenario

Comment: Try to specify full path including drive and path to the project root. Also run mvn with `-X` key to make output verbose. Check for the clue there.

Comment: already added and working now.Thanks